# android change actionbar to toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am trying to change `Actionbar` to `Toolbar`, I have successfully added `Toolbar` and removed `Actionbar`, but now the problem I have is that on my layout there will be a blank space above my toolbar where the `Actionbar` was at before. How can I move my `Toolbar` up so that it aligns with the top of the screen?

**I changed style to:**

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>>
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/header_bg_02">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot of result, the pink bar is my toolbar]

Comment: Did you add `<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` in your style xml?

Comment: @ArnisShaykh adding that still leaves a blank space above toolbar

Comment: Provide your layout file include Parent layout.

Comment: @SatanPandeya No I only changed the parent, how should I customize it?

Comment: Your code works fine. Strange, you don't get it .

Comment: show me this  android:background="@drawable/header_bg_02"\

Comment: @sushantgosavi this is the pink bar in my screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.i am using this

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
```

And my Apptheme is this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

Hope its help.:)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I am still getting a blank space above the tool bar following your suggestion.

Comment: please remove the padding.that all in your layout.

Comment: Hi, i tried to experiment by using your exact code but it i;m still facing the same problem

Comment: can you attach screenshot of the app??

Comment: please remove the drawable and then check?

Comment: Hi, removing the drawable just makes changes the background back to its default color, I have added the screenshot

Comment: remove all the parent and child add my code still the same output?create a new layout and add my above code to xml also create a new java file hope this helps.:)

Comment: Using your code I got an extra bar similar to the bar that contains the time, wifi icons right above my toolbar and the blank space still exists

Comment: i tried your code on my studio its perfectly working.just add this line    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar); its work fine

Comment: I'm using it in a fragment, maybe that is the problem, I'll try and let you know

Comment: i think i got your error.if you are using activity to fragment first disabled the visiblity of items in activity and then replace the view.hope this helps:)

Comment: You have the blank space from your activity not in fragment Happy Coding.:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132909/discussion-between-pratik-mohanrao-gondil-and-jerryko).

Comment: Its accepted answer, but why did it work?
means what was the cause etc not explained in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call **setSupportActionBar**?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutResource());
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

See this for a complete guide: [material-design-everywhere](http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/)

Answer (score 0):

First disable the `ActionBar` within `res/styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  </style>
</resources>
```

Include `ToolBar` in Activity layout file:

```
<LinearLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In your Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    // Find the toolbar view inside the activity layout
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // Sets the Toolbar to act as the ActionBar for this Activity window.
    // Make sure the toolbar exists in the activity and is not null
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

**Note**:

- You'll want to add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the parent layout of the Toolbar to ensure that the height of the activity is calculated correctly.
- When using the support library, make sure that you are importing `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` and not `android.widget.Toolbar`.

I include this information from [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar). Refer this for more.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I am still getting a blank space above the tool bar following your suggestion.

Comment: I had tested it. It works fine. Just remove all the `padding` from your Parent layout. e.g. LinearLayout like above.

Comment: I tested your code, it also works fine .  May be try this solution, by creating new project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put theme for that activity in AndroidMenifiest.xml file like

```
       <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

Other code looking fine